# Login doesn't work sometimes on wildfly 10.1.0.Final high availability cluster

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, authentication, wildfly, jaas

I request secured page and wildfly redirect me to login page. After I enter credentials usually it redirects me to secured page. But sometimes nothing  happens and I stay at login page. And there are no errors in log.

web.xml has distributable tag. Session replication is enabled and working. For testing i used nginx without sticky session, that sends each request to another node. And if login succeeded it works well. But sometimes I experience this login problem. Sticky session doesn't help. Apache with mod_cluster doesn't help. The problem exists also when only one node is running.

Do you have any ideas?

Log:

```
12:47:10,265 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00200: Begin isValid, principal: org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.AccountImpl$AccountPrincipal@18f4e, cache entry: null
12:47:10,389 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00209: defaultLogin, principal: org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.AccountImpl$AccountPrincipal@18f4e
12:47:10,389 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00221: Begin getAppConfigurationEntry(test-policy), size: 6
12:47:10,389 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00224: End getAppConfigurationEntry(test-policy), AuthInfo: AppConfigurationEntry[]:
[0]
LoginModule Class: my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule
ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required
Options:
name=dsJndiName, value=...
name=principalsQuery, value=...
name=keyStoreAlias, value=...
name=hashUserPassword, value=true
name=rolesQuery, value=...
name=keyStorePath, value=...
name=hashAlgorithm, value=...

12:47:10,393 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Initializing started
12:47:10,393 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00236: Begin initialize method
12:47:10,393 DEBUG [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00281: Password hashing activated, algorithm: ..., encoding: BASE64, charset: null, callback: null, storeCallBack: null
12:47:10,393 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00262: Module options [dsJndiName: ..., principalsQuery: ..., rolesQuery: ..., suspendResume: true]
12:47:10,413 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Initializing finished
12:47:10,413 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Login started
12:47:10,413 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00240: Begin login method
12:47:10,421 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Creating password hash started
12:47:10,426 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Creating password hash finished
12:47:10,426 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00263: Executing query SELECT ... as Password ...
12:47:10,433 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00241: End login method, isValid: true
12:47:10,433 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Login finished with true
12:47:10,433 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Commit started
12:47:10,433 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00242: Begin commit method, overall result: true
12:47:10,433 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00263: Executing query SELECT ... as Role ...
12:47:10,435 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00263: Executing query SELECT ... as Role ...
12:47:10,442 DEBUG [default task-1] [my.test.auth.RSADatabaseServerLoginModule] Commit finished with true
12:47:10,442 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00210: defaultLogin, login context: javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext@44f3c60b, subject: Subject(1679664219).principals=org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal@926329001(gel)org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup@309931210(Roles(members:MANAGER))org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup@309931210(CallerPrincipal(members:gel))
12:47:10,443 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00207: updateCache, input subject: Subject(1679664219).principals=org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal@926329001(gel)org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup@309931210(Roles(members:MANAGER))org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup@309931210(CallerPrincipal(members:gel)), cached subject: Subject(129825702).principals=org.jboss.security.SimplePrincipal@926329001(gel)org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup@309931210(Roles(members:MANAGER))org.jboss.security.SimpleGroup@309931210(CallerPrincipal(members:gel))
12:47:10,444 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00208: Inserted cache info: org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager$DomainInfo@58959e96
12:47:10,444 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00201: End isValid, result = true
12:47:10,533 TRACE [default task-1] [org.jboss.security] PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

Comment: Hello, I am having similar issue on JBoss EAP 7 which is based on Wildfly 10.1.  I am sharing my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454068/load-balancing-cluster-not-working-with-apache-http-server-2-4-6-and-jboss-eap-7